# when I use g++ on the command line, the clang++ compiler is used on the Mac OS

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, g++, clion

I know that gnu gcc compiler is preinstalled on Mac OS. But for some reason CLion does not see it. And moreover, when compiling in the console, clang++ was hung up on the g++ command. How to fix it so that CLion sees it and compiles through it, and so that gnu gcc is used in the console

I deleted XCode and CLion couldn't find anything at all, and XCode takes up a lot of space and I don't use it. I want to use GNU gcc on my Mac

Comment: *I know that gnu gcc compiler is preinstalled on Mac OS.*  I did not know that.  I did `brew install gcc` to install GCC, and use `g++-12` to run the compiler/linker.

Comment: https://imgur.com/7VI49de https://imgur.com/ijQ3A6B here they are both in the same folder

Comment: As far as I'm aware the default tool chain installed on mac os is clang/llvm -- but it's installed in such a way that you invoke the compiler as gcc, g++ etc.  If you really *do* have the gnu tool chain installed then you might want to try using the full paths to the various components.

Comment: @Baby_Legioner No, Mac OS just links gcc to clang and g++ to clang++. There is only Clang. (Why they do that, you'll have to ask Apple.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gcc is **not** pre-installed on macOS. `gcc --version` would show that it's actually clang. In fact, no C or C++ compiler is pre-installed, if we want to be technically correct.

Uninstalling XCode uninstalled your compiler as well. That shouldn't be a surprise, as installing XCode is probablly how you got the compiler in the first place. If you just want the command line tools, you can `xcode-select --install` them. That command may require `sudo` privileges.

You will still not have gcc at this point, just an alias that points to clang. You would then follow the instructions to install [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) and install gcc via the `brew` command. Once the installation finishes, you will be given instructions. You need to follow them, otherwise you'll still be using the aliased clang.

Or you could just use what's provided by default, as my guess is that you're not going to be writing anything that actually *requires* gcc.

Comment: They are not exactly "alias", right? The `gcc` , `g++`, `llvm-gcc` and `llvm-g++` are the actual compiler binaries, not symbolic links or stub files. They are executable files that represent the Clang compiler and related tools in macOS.

Comment: I might be playing fast and loose to a degree with the word alias but if `gcc` literally says it's clang, then the word alias seems fair to me. The distinction in this case does not make the answer clearer or better.